# Oracle SQL hierarchical query from bottom to top

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-query

I have a table where I want to go from bottom to top using hierarchical queries.

The problem is that I need the get the value of one column from root (top) using `CONNECT_BY_ROOT`, but since I reverse the way the hierarchical query works (reverse the prior in connect by and the start with), this function (`CONNECT_BY_ROOT`) consider my 'start with' row as level 1 (root) then gets me this value.

In other words, I want a way to reverse the `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` to get me the value of a column from the last possible level and not the root.

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| ID | ID_PARENT | VALUE |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 |      null |     5 |
|  2 |         1 |     9 |
|  3 |         2 |  null |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

I want to get the value of ID = 1 (5) to the ID = 3 like this:

```
+----+-------+------------+
| ID | VALUE | VALUE_root |
+----+-------+------------+
|  1 |  5    |      5     |
|  2 |  9    |      5     | 
|  3 |  null |      5     |
+----+-------+------------+
```

I tried this but all I get is `null` as value_root:

```
SELECT id,
CONNECT_BY_ROOT VALUE as VALUE_root
FROM my_table
START WITH ID = 3
CONNECT BY ID = PRIOR ID_PARENT
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that in my real system I'm dealing with millions of rows of data, the reason why I'm reversing the hierachical queries in first place is to make it better in terms of performance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may retrieve the root (which is a bottom node in your case) for all the tree upwards and then apply analytical function partitioned by the root to translate parent value to all the tree nodes. This is also possible for multiple nodes in `start with`.

```
with src (id, parentid, val) as (
  select 1, cast(null as int), 5 from dual union all
  select 2, 1, 9 from dual union all
  select 3, 2, null from dual union all
  select 4, 2, null from dual union all
  select 5, null, 10 from dual union all
  select 6, 5, 7 from dual
  
)
select
  connect_by_root id as tree_id
  , id
  , parentid
  , val
  , max(decode(connect_by_isleaf, 1, val))
      over(partition by connect_by_root id) as val_root
from src
start with id in (3, 4, 6)
connect by id = prior parentid

order by 1, 2, 3
```

| TREE_ID | ID | PARENTID | VAL | VAL_ROOT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | - | 5 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 9 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | - | 5 |
| 4 | 1 | - | 5 | 5 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 9 | 5 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | - | 5 |
| 6 | 5 | - | 10 | 10 |
| 6 | 6 | 5 | 7 | 10 |

Comment: I get this error : 
`unable to extend temp segment by %s in tablespace %s`
I'm dealing with huge data not only 3 rows, is there any other way ?

Comment: Hmm, another way is recursive CTE, but I think it will require more or less the same amount of memory. Does this error appear when you `start with` a single id?

Comment: when I put a single ID it works perfectly.. but it's kind of more complicated than that.. I have to start with `date = today` column so I can select all data of today and calculte their val_root.. (it comes with null as value)
When I do this it doesnt work it gets me val_root of all IDs of today as one unique val_root which is wrong value.

Comment: Then your `connect by` is not properly defined. You need to provide appropriate sample data and desired output. Maybe hierarchical query is not what should be used

Comment: @akadri01 For all the leaves with the same grand parent. This is what you've described as a requirement in your question. Or is there any different rule? What about the hierarchy: there's no way to traverse the hierarchy without recursive query

Comment: My mistake.. your solution seems to work perfectly.. I just want to know an additional thing.. how can I do it but to transfer the actual value of the leaf to the root ?
in your example if I have val = 9 in id=2 I want id=1 to have val=9 and not 5 ?

Comment: @akadri01 each child should have a value of a parent? It is a simple join without recursive query at all

Comment: can you be more specific please? would be good with an example please

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there

```
 SELECT id,
        value,
        CONNECT_BY_ROOT VALUE as VALUE_root
   FROM your_table
  START WITH ID = 1
CONNECT BY prior ID = ID_PARENT
```

Comment: Not exactly what I want.. I forgot to mention that in my real system I'm dealing with milions of datas so for better performance I really need to start from ID=3 and go up.
Also, I normally don't know which ID is root of my ID=3 so I have to start with ID_PARENT is null and it'll take huge amount of time and ressources.
I hope this explains why I have to start from ID=3.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query here I have just updated the START WITH condition and CONNECT BY clause -

```
SELECT id,
CONNECT_BY_ROOT VALUE as VALUE_root
FROM my_table
START WITH ID = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = ID_PARENT;
```

[Fiddle Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5bf27b/9)

Comment: Not exactly what I want.. I forgot to mention that in my real system I'm dealing with milions of datas so for better performance I really need to start from ID=3 and go up. Also, I normally don't know which ID is root of my ID=3 so I have to start with ID_PARENT is null and it'll take huge amount of time and ressources. I hope this explains why I have to start from ID=3

Answer (score 0):

One posibility is to *first* perform a hierarchical query starting from the root  - to get the *root node* for each row.

In the *second* step you perform the bottom up query (starting in all *leaves* nodes) and use the pre-calculated *root node*

Below the solution using [Recursive Subquery Factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)

```
with hir (id, id_parent, value, value_root) as
(select id, id_parent, value, value value_root
from tab 
where id_parent is null
union all
select tab.id, tab.id_parent, tab.value, hir.value_root
from hir
join tab on tab.id_parent = hir.id
),
hir2 (id, id_parent, value, value_root) as 
(select id, id_parent, value, value_root from hir 
where ID in (select id from tab /* id of leaves */
             minus
             select id_parent from tab)
union all
select hir.id, hir.id_parent, hir.value, hir.value_root
from hir2
join hir on hir2.id_parent = hir.id 
)
select id,value, value_root  
from hir2
;

        ID      VALUE VALUE_ROOT
---------- ---------- ----------
         3                     5
         2          9          5
         1          5          5
```

Nte that the order of the row `3, 2, 1` is the bottom up order that you want, but fail to reach in your example output.